# Как отнести текстовые строки к категориям в R?

Tags: r, nlp, классификация, работа-с-текстом, обработка-данных

Есть ответы людей на вопрос "Почему вы не покупете моющие средства марки Х?". Необходимо отнести каждый ответ к категории, но списка категорий нет (возможно, его потребуется создать). Для решения этой задачи я построила dtm матрицу в R и применила функцию LDA. В результате получила список тем и вероятности попадания каждого ответа в эту тему. Но темы получились расплывчатыми и непонятными. То есть очевидных тем "Цена", "Качество" и тд. там нет. 
Есть идея создать список категорий и соотнести половину ответов с этими категориями. Затем построить дерево решений или логистическую регрессию, чтобы предсказать категории оставшейся части ответов. 
Я новичок в НЛП и машинном обучении и очень нуждаюсь в совете. Какой метод можно использовать для разбиения текстовых строк на категории? Обязательно ли при этом сразу определять список категорий?

P.S. Работаю в R

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется конкретных тем, то я бы создал словари уникальных слов для каждой темы, а дальше взвешивал бы строку, на основании слов ассоциированных с темой. Такая разновидность sentiment analysis.

Посмотрите книжку [Text Mining with R](https://www.tidytextmining.com/), там подробно обсуждается как LDA так и другие NLP задачи.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А каким способом вы бы сравнивали строку со словами из каждой темы?

Comment: Ну если у нас есть строка c "w1 w2 w3 w4", если w1 и w2 из темы 1, w4 из темы 2, то, в соответствующих столбцах добавлять 2 и 1 и 0, а дальше уже придумать метрику, если все легко, достаточно будет найти максимум, если все плохо, то нужно больше исхитрятся.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить об LDA, то стоит обратить внимание на две вещи:

1) Стоп-слова, которые Вы удаляете, важны. Если Вы этого не делаете, то,возможно, стоит:)

-Пакет stopwords ("rus") должен помочь, но стоит посмотреть, не удаляется ли что то лишнее.

-Второй способ- удалить наиболее частотные слова, кроме тех, которые важны для расшифровки получившихся тем (возможно, Вы использовали пакет и удалили лишнего.

2) Полученные темы в LDA очень часто корявые и не очевидные:) Здесь либо полагаться на искусство их трактовки, либо играть с числом тем, которое задается в lda. В прекрасной книге @aGricolaMZ вроде было описание тестов полученной модели. Тут либо по ним, либо, если есть время, играть с числом тем, смотря на частотные слова и наиболее вероятные тексты для каждой из тем. Теоретически, Вы просто могли задать либо слишком маленькое, либо слишком большое число тем.

P.S. а сколько всего ответов и есть какие либо метаданные?

Comment: Дима, спасибо за ответ! Всего 60 ответов, и они довольно короткие, всего одно предложение. В дальнейшем ответов может быть больше, но и они будут тоже короткими. Стоп-слова я удаляла с помощью stopwords и использовала TFIDF. Провозившись некоторое время с LDA, прихожу к выводу, что это не самый удачный метод, так как все же ответы короткие и не учитываются синонимы. Наверное, LDA хорош для более длинных текстов. Буду пробовать классификацию Берта.